# Can I refactor this to not use method calls?

Tags: objective-c, cgrect

Let's say I have these methods:

```
+(CCSprite *)a {
    return [self shapeFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 224, 224, 288) rotate:0];
}

+(CCSprite *)b {
    return [self shapeFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 224, 224, 288) rotate:0];
}

+(CCSprite *)c {
    return [self shapeFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 100, 50, 50) rotate:0];
}

+(CCSprite *)d {
    return [self shapeFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 100, 50, 50) rotate:90];
}
```

There's redundancy, so I could refactor it like:

```
+(CCSprite *)a {
    return [self shapeFromRect:[self abRect] rotate:0];
}

+(CCSprite *)b {
    return [self shapeFromRect:[self abRect] rotate:0];
}

+(CCSprite *)c {
    return [self shapeFromRect:[self cdRect] rotate:0];
}

+(CCSprite *)d {
    return [self shapeFromRect:[self cdRect] rotate:90];
}

+(CGRect)abRect {
    return CGRectMake(0, 224, 224, 288);
}

+(CGRect)cdRect {
    return CGRectMake(0, 100, 50, 50);
}
```

But I am wondering, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Is there a way I could store these CGRects in a typedef enum or other form of constant so I don't have to perform method calls?

Comment: You can store the _rects_ as literals, yes: `(CGRect){0, 224, 224, 288}`, but that's unlikely to change the performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
+ (CCSprite *)sprite:(NSInteger)type
{
    float r = (type == 3)? 90 : 0;
    if (type < 2) {
        return [self shapeFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 224, 224, 288)] rotate:r];
    } else {
        return [self shapeFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 100, 50, 50)] rotate:r];
    }
}
```

maybe something similar to that?

Comment: Or make an `enum`: `enum { SpriteTypeA, SpriteTypeB, SpriteTypeC, SpriteTypeD }; typedef NSUInteger SpriteType;`, and you could then test `type >= SpriteTypeC`.